# Copula of $a_1(X_1),a_2(X_2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two continuous random variables and $C: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ their copula.
Let $a_1,a_2:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ two continuous functions, which are strictly monotone on the range of $X_1$, respectively $X_2$. 
I want to calculate the copula $\tilde{C}:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ of $U_1:=a_1(X_1)$ and $U_2:=a_2(X_2)$.

1. Let $F_1$ be the distribution function of $X_1$, $F_2$ be the distribution function of $X_2$ and $F$ be their joint distribution function. Let $G_1$ be the distribution function of $U_1$, $G_2$ the distribution function of $U_2$ and $G$ be their joint distribution function.

First, we notice that $a_1,a_2$ are both invertible on the respective ranges since they are continuous and strictly monotone in this ranges. So

$G_i(x)=P(U_i\le x)=P(a_i(X_i)\le x)=P(X_i\le a_i^{-1}(x))=F_i(a_i^{-1}(x))$ $\qquad$ for $i\in\{1,2\}.$

**First attempt:**

Applying Sklar's theorem we get

$\tilde C(G_1(u),G_2(v))=G(u,v)=P(U_1\le u, U_2\le v)=P(a_1(X_1)\le u, a_2(X_2)\le v)=P(X_1\le a_1^{-1}(u),X_2\le a_2^{-1}(v))=F(a_1^{-1}(u),a_2^{-1}(v))=C(F_1(a_1^{-1}(u)),F_2(a_2^{-1}(v)))=C(G_1(u),G_2(v)).$

So the copulas are the same.

**Second attempt:**

Here we want apply the inverse of Sklar's theorem:

$\tilde C(u,v)=P(G_1(U_1)\le u,G_2(U_2)\le v)=P(F_1(a_1^{-1}(U_1))\le u, F_2(a_2^{-1}(U_2))\le v)=P(F_1(X_1)\le u, F_2(X_2)\le v)=P(X_1\le F_1^{-1}(u),X_2\le F_2^{-1}(v))=F(F_1^{-1}(u),F_2^{-1}(v))=C(u,v).$

**But I think we can disprove this by a simple example:**
Choose $a_1(x)=x$, $a_2(x)=1/x$ and $X_1=X_2>0$ positive r.v., i.e. $U_1=X_1$ and $U_2=1/X_1$. Hence $F_1=F_2=G_1$. The functions $a_1$ and $a_2$ are invertible on $\mathbb R^+$.

$\tilde C(u,v)=P(G_1(U_1)\le u,G_2(U_2)\le v)=P(F_1(X_1))\le u, 1-F_2(1/U_2)\le v)=P(F_1(X_1)\le u, 1-F_1(X_1)\le v)=P(1-v \le F_1(X_1)\le u)=P(F_1^{-1}(1-v) \le X_1\le F_1^{-1}(u))=F_1(F_1^{-1}(u))-F_1(F_1^{-1}(1-v))=u+v-1\ne \min\{u,v\}=C(u,v).$

That means that in my proof there is a mistake. Does anyone find the mistake?
I think my proof is only valid for functions which are strictly increasing on the image of the corresponding random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If function $a$ is strictly monotone and increasing then $$a(X)\leq u \iff X \leq a^{-1}(u).$$ 
And for decreasing function vice versa: 
$$a(X)\leq u \iff X \geq a^{-1}(u).$$

Your proof is valid for strictly increasing functions. And in counterexample you take the second function decreasing.

Comment: The copula of a vector with all components strictly monotone increasing/decreasing functions w.r.t. the same random variable is always the comonotonicity copula $C(u_1,\dots,u_d)=\min\{u_1,\dots,u_d\}$. And the Copula of a twodimensional random vector with one component strictly increasing and one strictly decreasing w.r.t. the same random varialbe is always the countermonotonicity copula $C(u_1,u_2)=\max\{u_1+u_2-1,0\}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right.